# What's the advantage of using enum string over string in D?

Tags: enums, constants, d

`enum` in D can be used as constant as follows:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    enum secondsPerDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
    // enum int secondsPerDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
    writeln(secondsPerDay * 1024);

    enum fileName = "list.txt";
    writeln(fileName, typeof(fileName).stringof);

    auto fileName2 = "list.txt";
    writeln(fileName2, typeof(fileName2).stringof);
}
```

Then, what's the advantage of using enum over auto (string) when string is immutable anyway? These are returned results.

```
88473600
list.txtstring
list.txtstring
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a lot of difference with strings. Generally though, the difference between immutable and enum is that enums are always evaluated at compile time. immutable values are only compile time evaluated in static contexts.

Another difference is that enums are kinda like copy/pasted to the usage site. Observe:

```
enum array = [1,2,3];
void main() {
      auto arr = array; // this actually allocates a new array [1,2,3]
      static immutable arr2 = array; // this doesn't
}
```

The real difference there is `static` rather than `immutable`, which puts the data in a static data segment, but it still contrasts with `enum` which just creates a compile-time value.

Anyway, with a plain string, this makes no difference. `enum` comes into play more when you are using it on a function result or mutable array, where the compile time bit may mean a function call is removed at runtime, or the "pasted constant" bit might mean an added allocation at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between immutable(char)[] (aka string) and immutable(char[]) ( an enum string):

```
void main() 
{ 
   string s = "string1";
   enum e = "enum1";

   s = e; // allowed
   e = s; // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation found here: http://dlang.org/enum.html

**Manifest Constants**

If there is only one member of an anonymous enum, the { } can be omitted:

```
enum i = 4;      // i is 4 of type int
enum long l = 3; // l is 3 of type long
```

Such declarations are not lvalues, meaning their address cannot be taken. They exist only in the memory of the compiler.

```
enum size = __traits(classInstanceSize, Foo);  // evaluated at compile-time
```

Using manifest constants is an idiomatic D method to force compile-time evaluation of an expression.